# Accessing a global function from an inner function with the same name

Tags: python, function, nested-function

I have the following code:

```py
def A():
    return 2

def B():
    def A():
        return 3

    return A()

print(B())
```

The result is 3 because `return A()` uses inner function `A()` of `B()` instead of function `A()`. Is it possible to call function `A()` (the one that return 2) inside function `B()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overriding the global `A` with your own local implementation. You should still be able to call the global one using the [`globals()` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834451/2011147) but note that what you are doing is not good practice:

```
return globals()["A"]()
```

Update: This is not good practice because it violates multiple principles of [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), such as *"Explicit is better than implicit"*,  *"Readability counts"*, and *"If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea"*.

Comment: @tdelaney I was trying out nested function and suddenly this question came into my mind. Ofc, I know that this is a bad practice.

Comment: @VinhQuangTran- it isn't necessarily bad practice to use `globals()` to access variables at module scope. It seems odd in your example, but then its just a trivial test program.

Comment: @tdelaney Correct, I elaborated it a little more in my edit. What is bad practice is not the use of `globals()` but to override global names with locals, leading to unexpected and hard-to-find bugs.